# Can I get more reopen votes for this question?

Tags: discussion

[This question on bridge bidding in NT auctions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25505/bridge-which-transfer-do-you-use-with-both-majors-one-5-carder-and-another-4), which although brief is quite adequately described, has been closed as too broad. The problem described is a quite common one for bridge beginners and early intermediates, and arises in all bidding systems. Although the answers will outline various conventional techniques as the existing (very short) one does, there is much that can be said on how to handle this common problem in the absence of specific techniques.

I would like to make a stab at such an answer, but am prevented from doing so 
by the closure on the question. Please help out by voting to reopen.

Thanks very much.